# Обратный отсчет jquery.flipCountDown

Tags: php, jquery

У меня есть php переменная

```
$date // unix time (int 1453884009)
```

Она содержит время до которого нужно производить отсчет

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        location.href=location.href
    }, 3600000);

    var dater = <?php echo (integer) $date ?>;

    $('#clocker').flipcountdown({
        beforeDateTime: new Date(dater / 1000)
    });
});
```

Но ничего не происходит, счетчики по нулям

Comment: `beforeDateTime: new Date(dater / 1000)` скорее всего умноженое на 1000 так `beforeDateTime: new Date(dater * 1000)`

Comment: @Naumov так счетчики тоже по нулям.

Comment: что в переменной $date и dater в php var_dump($date), console.log() что говорят?

Comment: @Naumov int 1453884009 и там и там. С умножением работает но выводит 16810533:17:31:45 вместо 01:45

Comment: А если попробывать просто dater без деления и умножения?

Comment: @Naumov тогда таймер по нулям

Comment: Ага значит можно прибавить количество секонд в 1:45 и получить то что нужно. для эксперемента можно +100 попробывать